# I can't install python on vm, error setup

Tags: python, installation

I want to install Python on a VM, Google Cloud, and I am encountering the following error:

> 0x80070659.

I can't bypass this error using regedit or administrator tool. In this machine, I have Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking and installing as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with admin credentials. If its not working then check whether any policy is defined under Software Restriction Policies in Local Security Settings. 
If there are no policies defined then create a new policy and double click on enforcement.

Comment: where i find admin credentials?

Comment: Right click and "Run as Administrator"